# How to prevent firing input onChange after clicking on label?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, label

I need to change checkbox state only by clicking input(checkbox) component.

Please suggest how to prevent input onchange being fired when label clicked?

```
<label className="selection_label">{title}<input value={value} checked={state[value]} type="checkbox" onChange={this.onCheckboxChange(value)} /> <span /></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Close the label before the input, like:

```
<label className="selection_label">{title}</label> // <---

<input value={value} checked={state[value]} type="checkbox" onChange={this.onCheckboxChange(value)} />
```

And your `span` tag is in the wrong place, either remove it or move it to the right position.